# Word for someone with common sense?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word for someone with common sense other than 'sensible'?

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus?

Comment: EL&U doesn't accept [tag:single-word-requests] that simply ask for a word without any context for how it will be used. If all you want is a substitute word, then please use a thesaurus (e.g. [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com)), as that is what they are designed for. The question could be reopened if you [edit] it to include information about how you will use the word, e.g. an example sentence or situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try **reasonable**:

> (of a person) having sound judgment; fair and **sensible**

([Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reasonable))

Also, **rational** might fit, depending on the context:

> Able to think sensibly or logically

([Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rational))